# How to set a vue component to the background

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a vue component that uses the tsparticles library, and I would like to set is as background as it is overlapping over all my other components, can anyone help as to how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be running but not displayed expect when booleanToShow is true:

```
<div v-show="booleanToShow"></div>
```

If you want to remove it from the DOM (and stop it from running)

```
<div v-if="booleanToToggle"></div>
```

Comment: I want it to display just not in the front but as background animation and put other components on top of it

Answer (score 0):

You can set `tsparticles` to be in background using the `backgroundMode` property.

You can see a working sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-colden-uvs85?file=/src/App.vue

The property `backgroundMode` sets the `tsparticles` canvas to full screen, it's an object with two properties: `enable` and `zIndex`.

- `enable` (boolean): (obviously) enables the full screen mode
- `zIndex` (number): sets the canvas element `z-index` property to whatever you want

A sample of `backgroundMode`:

```js
{
    /* root object */
    backgroundMode: {
        enable: true,
        zIndex: -1
    }
    /* root object */
}
```

You can set the `background` property too, it's a shorthand to the CSS `background` property.

You can use that property to change the canvas background color, for example:

```js
{
    /* root object */
    background: {
        color: "#000"
    }
    /* root object */
}
```

If you set a negative `zIndex` you need to use `detectsOn: "window"` in `interactivity` object to keep mouse events working.